# RxJava and Retrofit2: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I try to combine few requests at Observable.zip(...), but I got an error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. What I'm doing wrong?

```
Call<EmployeeInfo> companyInfo = apiService.employee();
    companyInfo.enqueue(new Callback<EmployeeInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<EmployeeInfo> call, Response<EmployeeInfo> response) {
            EmployeeInfo info = response.body();
            Observable.zip(
                    apiService.getOrders("https://exaple.com"),
                    apiService.getOrders("https://exaple.com"),
                    apiService.getOrders("https://exaple.com"),
                    apiService.companyInfo("1"), new Func4<Orders, Orders, Orders, CompanyInfo, OrdersDataWrapper>() {
                        @Override
                        public OrdersDataWrapper call(Orders currentOrders, Orders waitingOrders, Orders enterOrders, CompanyInfo companyInfo) {
                            OrdersDataWrapper data = new OrdersDataWrapper();
                            return data;
                        }
                    }).onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, OrdersDataWrapper>() {
                @Override
                public OrdersDataWrapper call(Throwable throwable) {
                    return null;
                }
            })
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Action1<OrdersDataWrapper>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(OrdersDataWrapper alDataWrapper) {
                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<EmployeeInfo> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: u r missing subscribeOn

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the .observeOn, but not the .subscribeOn, so RxJava is subscribing and observing on the main thread. Add a .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) so that the calls are executed on the background thread.